# How to create public key for encryption in keychain using ipad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, public-key

i need to encrypt text using rsa algorithm for which i need public key.
i want to generate public key inside the app and use it for encryption. i have to generate key of type SecKeyRef. how do i do that?

Comment: i want to generate public key inside the app and use it for encryption. i have to generate key of type SecKeyRef. how do i do that?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again.  You can place a bounty on this one if you aren't getting sufficient answers.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know exactly what you want to do, but this might help you,

[iOS - Creating SecKeyRef from exponent+modulus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942712/ios-creating-seckeyref-from-exponentmodulus)

[Keychain Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html)

[iOS Keychain Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558252/ios-keychain-security)

[Using an RSA public key generated by OpenSSL in iOS](http://blog.flirble.org/2011/01/05/rsa-public-key-openssl-ios/)

I hope it will help you

Comment: Your link is about the Mac's keychain, however the poster wants to know about the iOS keychain.

Comment: @DarkDust Then he needs to look into http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558252/ios-keychain-security

Comment: Right. Please edit your question accordingly (people often don't bother reading comments).

Comment: @DarkDust I think that should do the job

Comment: I've edited the answer to beautify the non-SO links, otherwise +1.